# question about bidual normed space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider a Banach $\mathbb{R}$-space E and an element $u\in E''$ such that :
for all sequence $\phi_n\in E'$ which $\sigma(E',E)$-converges to $\phi \in E'$, one has $\lim u(\phi_n)=u(\phi)$.
Is it true that there is some $x\in E$ such that $u(f)=f(x)$ for all $f\in E'$ ?

remark : it is not clear for me that $u:E'\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma(E',E)$-continuous

Comment: looks like a homework problem

Comment: Really, Nik?  It does not to me, but I might assign it the next time I teach a course in Banach space theory.

@Terry: The answer is yes if E is separable but no in general; e.g. if $E=\ell_\infty$, because $\ell_\infty$ is a Shur space (that is, every weak`$^*$` convergent sequence in `$\ell_\infty^*$` is weakly convergent).

Comment: Is Shur space = Schur space?

Comment: @Bill: based on the way it's phrased and the fact that there are easy counterexamples (I was thinking of the continuous functions on the extended long line)

Comment: Voting to close to keep MO from resurrecting it.